# How to code an atomic transaction in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

I have multiple `select`, `insert` and `update` statement to complete a transaction, but I don't seem to be able to ensure all statements to be successful before committing the changes to table.

The transaction doesn't seem to be atomic.

I do have `begin` and `end` in my function but transaction doesn't seem to be atomic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.testarray(salesid integer, items json) RETURNS         integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
 resu text;
 resu2 text := 'TH';
 ssrow RECORD;
 oserlen int := 0;
 nserlen int := 0;
 counter int := 0;
begin

 select json_array_length(items::json->'oserial') into oserlen;
 while counter < nserlen loop
   select items::json#>>array['oserial',counter::text] into resu;
   select * into strict ssrow from salesserial where fk_salesid=salesid     and serialnum=resu::int;
   insert into stockloct(serialnum,fk_barcode,source,exflag)     values(ssrow.serialnum,ssrow.fk_barcode,ssrow.fk_salesid,true);
   counter := counter + 1;
 end loop; 

 counter := 0;
 select json_array_length(items::json->'nserial') into nserlen;
 while counter < nserlen loop
   select items::json#>>array['nserial',counter::text,'serial'] into resu2;
   select * into ssrow from stockloc where serialnum=resu2::int;
   insert into salesserial(fk_salesid,serialnum,fk_barcode)     values(salesid,ssrow.serialnum,ssrow.fk_barcode);
   counter := counter + 1;
 end loop;
 select items::json#>'{nserial,0,serial}' into resu2;
 return resu;
end;
$$;
```

Even when the first insert fails, the second insert seems to be able to succeed.

Comment: select * from testarray(1121,'{"oserial":["10002702","10002699"],"nserial":[{"serial":"10002704","price":"320.00"}]}');

Comment: A function *always* runs in a single transaction. If either `INSERT` fails, they will all be rolled back. There must be a misunderstanding; can you clarify your problem?

Comment: Hi, Thanks in advance. I am probably making some mistake. Here is my problem this loop [while counter < nserlen loop] shud select from salesserial and insert it into stockloct. i am intentionally feeding a nonexisting data to the select which shud result in 0 row and the insert shud fail and it does. I assume the second loop [while counter < nserlen loop] shud fail as well because the first loop failed but data has been inserted in the salesserial table via second loop

Answer (score 0):

I see that by “fail” you mean “does not insert any rows”.

That is not surprising since the first loop is never executed: both `counter` and `nserlen` are always 0.

Perhaps you mean the first `WHILE` condition to be `counter < oserlen`?

You also seem to br confused by PL/pgSQL's `BEGIN`: while it looks like the `BEGIN` that starts a transaction, it is quite different. It is just the “opening parenthesis” in a PL/pgSQL block.